# Sql select from a table but use another table value as where clause

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

How can I select * from `table posts` but using  table `network_follow.follower` as where condition?

I have table `posts`, column `by_user`

and table  `network_follow` column `follower`

I don't know if that's the case, can somebody help?

```
select * from posts where posts.by_user = network_follow.follower = user_logged
```

Comment: A table is not a `where` condition.  You need more explanation of what you want to do.  Sample data and desired results help.

Comment: select * from table `posts` where column `by_user` = table `network_follow` column `follower` = `"user_logged"`

Comment: You'll probably some kind of `JOIN` statement

Comment: I updated the question with more details, can you guys see

Comment: @Developer Please include the column names for the two tables.

Comment: I have table `posts`, column `by_user` 
and table  `network_follow` column `follower`

Comment: It is possible if there is any common column between the two tables and you join on the common column (between the two tables). Otherwise it is not possible.

Comment: See also "derived table"

Comment: Rick James, question as already solved, but could you post an answer how you would do it using `derived table` ? I will give you an upvote for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables and then  filter the `network_follow` table with the `WHERE` condition.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts AS p
JOIN network_follow AS n ON p.by_user = n.followed
WHERE n.follower = user_logged
```

Comment: works, great, showing just fine, but I am getting undefined variables when the logged_user is not following, user_2 how to fix? I think it's not a query problem but php while.

Comment: maybe I should fix with `isset()`?

Comment: Give the variables default values before the loop that processes the output.

Comment: set to blank right?

Comment: Whatever you want. Or maybe check whether the query returns any rows, and show different output in that case.

Comment: I made like this `$val = $post->rowCount();
if($val > 0){ //while here}` don't know if that's the correct way, but it solved

Comment: That's a common solution.